# Android Activity Memory

Tags: android

I am doing a lot of reading on this currently but thought it never hurts to ask a knowledgeable group of developers as well.
This is a popular issue and there seem to be a lot of different ways of handling it.

I have an Android application. It uses OpenGL so when it starts up does a fair amount of data loading both from disk and then in VRAM. When the screen is rotated as well as when the power button is pressed (to put the phone into sleep mode) I lose all data and the activity is killed.

I don't want this. The app takes about 7 seconds to boot up and load its data and it is really annoying if you just sleep your phone for a second then have to wait the app to load all again.

I am familiar with the app lifecycle as outlined by Google but having a hard time implementing a solution that works for my particular case.

Any suggestions? My overall goal is to preserve the following in memory when the phone sleeps are is rotated: 
1. App memory on heap
2. App memory in VRAM

Thanks!

So far:

```
public class MainActivity

    private FH_SurfaceView fGLSurfaceView;

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Check if the system supports OpenGL ES 2.0.
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();

        final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;
         if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            /* NEED TO DO SOMETHING HERE?? */
            return;
         }

        else{
            this.fGLSurfaceView = new FH_SurfaceView(this);
             setContentView(fGLSurfaceView);
        }    

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted some of your activity's code to make the question more concrete.

Comment: Defer your data loading to another thread.  It's likely getting killed due to ANR because it is blocking the main thread of your app doing the data load/processing.

Comment: @Larry: what is ANR? I only need to load the data once and it is all contained within my custom surfaceview class and its subclasses. I just dont want all the arrays etc wiped when the app is paused....

Comment: `It uses OpenGL so when it starts up does a fair amount of data loading both from disk and then in VRAM` . What does this mean?  Simly using OpenGL adds very little overhead.  What else are you loading? Textures?  Bitmaps?  Other?  The code you have shown does not relate to the symptoms you are seeing.

Comment: ANR = Application Not Responding.  If your main thread is ever blocked for more than 5 seconds the app process will be killed.  In practice your main thread should never be blocked for more than 100ms.  Though you really want to be able to handle 60fps, so 100ms is even slow.

Comment: `onPause()` will not cause your data arrays to be purged automatically.  After `onPause()` your `Activity` can be killed at any time, which would then cause the memory to be released.  But, as long as it is in the pause or stop state your memory/data will still be present.

Comment: @Simon: yes textures as well as some application data in arrays.

Comment: @Larry: Okay so I need to keep in the onPause() state I presume.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "keep in the onPause() state".  You cannot dictate what state you are in, you are just notified of the transition into the state.  The Android framework drives the state of the Activity, Fragment, Service, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `Activity` is holding a large amount of data. When the phone sleeps, it will likely target it to be destroyed for a variety of reasons, primarily to make sure there's memory for other tasks, but also because it might eating up processing cycles and Android knows it is not visible. Hence your problem. This does not happen to all apps, only "heavy" ones.

There may be nothing that you can do about this, but here are some suggestions:

1. Analyze your data loading. It might be that some parts are computationally expensive and therefore they are slowing the process, while other parts are heavy on memory but light on processing. Then in `onPause` dump the heavy memory part to improve the odds that Android won't kill your app. You might be able to get a 1-2 second load time instead of your current 7.
2. Consider creating a `Service` where the data resides and then binding to it in order to access it. Android does not expect a `Service` to be visible, and you can signal processing to cease in the `onPause` or `onStop` of your `Activity` to prevent Android from killing the service. I realize this is "tricky" as your data is currently in a custom `SurfaceView` class - and storing display data not on the UI thread is a pain.
3. Also, you might put the data into the `Application` class for similar reasons. The benefit of this is that you do not need binders to access the data. The drawback is that Android is more likely to destroy this than a `Service` I think (but that's experience talking, not testing - so, educated guess?). Also, messing with the `Application` class should be done with caution.
4. If all else fails, then try to provide an entertaining transition that acknowledges the silliness of the situation. In other words, communicating that you are aware of an unpleasant situation to a user is far better than ignoring it and hoping they don't mind.

Comment: The heavy processing is all handled by openGL. So I think that it could be a memory thing. I don't really know the limits though of how much is "too much". With the largeheap option in my AndroidManifest.xml file I get 256mb. I don't come anywhere close to using that. My total memory allocated on the heap at the max is under 10mb.  I could potentially free some up if need be but I wouldn't think this is what is killing the process. Thoughts? I am not totally familiar with how to properly store data in a "bundle" then access it later yet. Something to look into tonight.

Comment: There's no way it takes 7 seconds to load 10MB of data - that's like using an old WiFi access point (at about 10 Mbs). And you shouldn't even need the largeHeap option. So something else is happening - or else you're only looking at the main heap - openGL likely deals with native memory; read up on this: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear. I parse hundreds of megabytes of data using some sorting algorithms etc. BUT, in the end I only allocate about 10mb in space to hold onto. The reason I need the LargeHeap option is for my textures for OpenGL. Some of my textures are 60mb in size. But as the article points out these gets stored in video memory not on the heap. However, there is loading time to get them there and that is why I have a longer startup time.